# Why isinstance() method returning True (Python 3.xx)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not too familiar with the OOP side of Python yet so this is a bit above my head.

```
>>> a=[[2,3,4]]
>>> types = (list,str,int,str,int)
>>> b=isinstance(a,types)

True
```

No matter what type I add on after the list type, the expression always returns `True`.

I have read that `isinstance()` method accepts derived class types but I can't really convince myself I know whats going on here.

This returns true as well. Is it because all 3 belong to the same class?

```
>>> isinstance([], (tuple, list, set))
True
```

Comment: It's `True` if [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any). You're thinking it should be `True` if [`all`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because when you give a tuple of types as second argument to isinstance it works as 'OR' (or any) , it would return True , if the type of first argument is any of the types in that tuple.

Example -

```
>>> isinstance('asd',(str,bool,int))
True
```

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> In [1]: isinstance?
> ```
>
> Docstring:
>
> ```
> isinstance(object, class-or-type-or-tuple) -> bool
> ```
>
> Return whether an object is an instance of a class or of a subclass thereof.
>   With a type as second argument, return whether that is the object's type.
>   The form using a tuple, `isinstance(x, (A, B, ...))`, is a shortcut for:
>
> ```
> isinstance(x, A) or isinstance(x, B) or ... (etc.).
> ```
>
> Type:      `builtin_function_or_method`

So, it is actually a `or` statement. Very clear, right?

Answer (score 1):

Although a list `[]` is considered an *Iterator* in Python, just like tuple, dictionary and set, it is not derived from the same based class (unless you consider `object` as the base type, which is pretty much for every type).

Try this:

```
>>> [].__class__
<type 'list'>
>>> ().__class__
<type 'tuple'>
>>> {}.__class__
<type 'dictionary'>
>>> [].__class__.__bases__
<type 'object'>  # yeah sure
```

Like other have answered, giving a tuple to `isinstance()` is like saying this:

```
>>> type([]) in (tuple, list, set)
True
```

Classes like `tuple` and `list` are not subclasses derived from a same base class, they both just conform to a protocol of `Iterable` by providing `__inter__()` and `__next__()` methods. It's beauty of duck typing.